# HTTP запрос для загрузки json данных. Открывается 404

Tags: http

Не знаю куда копать.
Я не силен в http запросах. Но задачу решить не могу.
Пытаюсь скриптом (autohotkey) вытянуть json данные с этой страницы https://1xstavka.ru/results/  когда выбираешь дату в инспекторе в браузере посмотрел, происходит запрос на адрес https://1xstavka.ru/results/getmain?date=2020-02-18&showAll=true и возвращается json данные.
Но если делать то же самое скриптом то загружается страница 404. + если ссылку просто открыть в браузере тоже будет 404.
Я не могу понять, что не хватает для запроса? Правильные заголовки для сервера/куки? Какой-то редирект происходит? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: This website is not available in your country

Comment: Сайт определяет страну, кроме России может не пускать да. можно попробовать этот домен https://one-xzpofi.world/results/

Comment: `X-Requested-With` установите.

Comment: В хроме во вкладке сети есть `copy as curl`. Когда с этим освоитесь, у вас не будет больше подобных вопросов.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Все полетело как надо.